# Specify resources for DataGrid without using an inner tag

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I usually specify the clickettiness of the table using the following XAML.

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
      <EventSetter Event="MouseClick" Handler="ClickettyClick"/>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Just now, I noticed that the intellisense provided me with attribute *Resources* while **inside** the jawsy brackets of the tag *DataGrid*. Fueled by pure curiosity I went for it and got into something like this.

```
<DataGrid Resources="" />
```

Is the *Resources* attribute in the latter example equivalent to the inner tag *Grid.Resources* in the first one? If so, how can one formulate the contents of the string (i.e. parameters to the attribute) so that it corresponds to the multi-tag version?

I hardly think it's going to be a smoother way but: (a) one never knows and (b) it's always fun to learn new ways to juggle the code.

Comment: @Clemens Would you kindly point me to the page (or at least the section) where Nathan gives the answer to my specific question, please? (Also, please note that the answer is already provided by Glen Thomas below, so it's not the answer itself I'm looking for but rather verifying that the reading suggestions you've provided actually leads anywhere. I might be missing an interesting part of the book and I'm always keen on improving my research skills.)

Comment: Look for XAML attribute syntax vs XAML property element syntax. See [XAML Syntax In Detail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788723(v=vs.100).aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: I don't see anything that actually refers to my specific question there. It's just the general description (and I don't have access to my printed book so I had to use Google Books, still not finding the specifics I was looking for). Perhaps it's there in front of my nose and I don't realize it. Or perhaps you interpreted my question as a general request on tag syntax, which isn't really corresponding to the title. Or maybe we can rephrase the headline. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: If you take a closer look, you'll realize that certain things that can be written in element syntax can not be written in attribute syntax. There is especially no way of in-place object creation in attribute syntax as there is in element syntax, unless you have a specific markup extension. However, there is no such thing like a resource dictionary markup extension in the framework.

Comment: @Clemens Right. As Glen said. Although it'd be more convenient if he (and the resources on the net/in the books) would state that fact so explicitly clear as you just did. And that one'd be able to quickly look up that statement. I think you should post it as a reply for a better google. Meanwhile, I'm going to update Glen's reply with it and accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a resource dictionary resource

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="MyDictionary" 
                        Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<DataGrid Resources="{StaticResource MyDictionary}" />
```

Integrating the comments made by @Clemens, it should be pointed out very explicitly that certain things that can be written in **element syntax** can not be written in **attribute syntax**.

There is especially no way of in-place object creation in attribute syntax as there is in element syntax, unless one has a specific markup extension.

Furthermore, there is no such thing like a resource dictionary markup extension in the framework.

Comment: Is that a "no" to the first question? The one asking if it's possible to achieve the same settings as the multi-tag version but with the string-ish approach... Please feel welcome to provide a tiny example of the Dictionary1.xaml as well.

Comment: You can't enter some sort of magic string no; it would only support values of type ResourceDictionary, whether that be through Binding, StaticResource or DynamicResource or others. I don't believe it would be possible for a string to be parsed to a ResourceDictionary in the same way as Value="True" or Value="2", etc.